# How to find the marginal density given these restrictions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know how to find the marginal density I'm just a little confused how to do it with these restrictions. This is the problem:

$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\ 24y(1-x-y),  & \text{if x>0, y>0, x+y<1} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$

I don't know if I'm approaching this correctly because I haven't ever done a problem with these kinds of restrictions. I think the marginal density of X is $$\int_0^{1-x} f(x,y) \,dy$$

Is that correct? Also, then would the marginal density of y have the same integral or would it go from 0 to infinity?

Comment: $\checkmark$ That is correct.  The other marginal density will have a similar *form*. $\int_0^{1-y} f(x,y)\operatorname d x$.  This is not the same integral.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Okay great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)
 & = 24y(1−x−y) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1-y)}(x) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1-x)}(y)
\\[2ex]
f_{X}(x)
 & = \int_{\rm Y} 24y(1−x−y) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1-y)}(x) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1-x)}(y) \operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
 & = \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x) \int_0^{1-x} 24y(1−x)−24y^2 \operatorname d y  
\\[2ex]
f_{Y}(y)
 & = \int_{\rm X} 24y(1−x−y) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1-y)}(x) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1-x)}(y) \operatorname d x
\\[1ex]
 & = \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(y) \int_0^{1-y} 24y(1−y)-24yx \operatorname d x  
\end{align}$